# Mac OS X 10.6.8 with Synergy 1.8.5 Client can't click on dashboard nor Spotlight

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, synergy

I've got Synergy 1.7.6 server on a Gentoo box, and 1.8.5 on a Mac OS X Snow Leopard client (had to upgrade because of a 'spacebar sends S' bug fixed in 1.8.3). It works pretty much okay, but I'm having mouse clicking issues (which were present when it was matched to 1.7.6):

- I can't click on the small window that shows spotlight results
- I can't click on any dashboard applet
- clicking on another app's window doesn't trigger a menu update: I'm on Firefox and click on a Finder window, menu keeps showing Firefox and doesn't work if clicked

I'm sure all three cases are related. Sometimes shift+click makes it work again but it's not too long until it breaks again. Could this related to the "stuck keys" issue? I'm not sure if it is, but I couldn't find any question with my symptoms. Any known workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: It was not a Synergy problem. Works fine now.**

I was using an Ethernet cable from a VoIP phone. I noticed that transfer speed was very wrong, and it turned out to be a bad cable, it would negotiate gigabit speed but couldn't keep up. I set the Ethernet setup to 100 mbps and it worked fine. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

The likely cause of this is MacOS 10.6 being too out of date and unsupported. Synergy supports OS X 10.9 as a minimum. If possible, try upgrading the Mac to fix the issue.

Comment: I don't think it's officially supported, but I'm not having problems anymore with 1.8.5, problem was somewhere else.